# Why this Map method within Promise.all won't work correctly with MongoDB and Monk in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have order data in a Mongo database. I also have product information in the same database and I need to combine those.

If an order has multiple products I need to create copies of the order for each product. So if I have one order with to items there will be two otherwise identical orders with one of the products in each. (Data will be submitted as a CSV to service which won't accept multiple products on one line of data)

The problem is that when I try to get the product data for each order from the Mongo database with Monk only one version of each order with multiple items comes through to the CSV.

Everything goes well all the way to the **decorateProducts** function, which seems to cause the missing orders. The JSON array looks okay before that and is missing the orders after.

Here's the relevant code:

```
...

const decorateProducts = (order) => {
  if (typeof order[0] !== 'undefined' && order[0] !== null) {
  var prodId = order[0].productId;
  return collectionProducts.findOne({"_id": prodId})
  .then(currentProduct => {
    if (currentProduct) {
      var obj = {
        "email" : order[0].email,
        "firstName" : order[0].firstName,
        "lastName" : order[0].lastName,
        "location" : order[0].location,
        "orderNumber" : order[0].orderNumber,
        "orderId" : order[0].orderNumber,
        "orderDate" : order[0].orderDate,
        "productId" : order[0].productId,
        "productTitle" : currentProduct["productTitle"],
        "productImageUrl" : currentProduct["productImageUrl"],
        "productUrl" : currentProduct["productUrl"]
      }
    }
    else { obj = ""; }
    return obj;
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
};

...

  collectionOrders.find({})
  .then(orders => Promise.all(orders.map(order => processOrder(order))))
  .then(orders => Promise.all(orders.map(order => decorateProducts(order))))
  .then(orders => writeCsv(orders))
  .then(output => res.send(output))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because inside `decorateProducts` you're returning an object. Try returning a `Promise` instead so that the object is still thennable.

```
const decorateProducts = (order) => {
  if (typeof order[0] !== 'undefined' && order[0] !== null) {
    var prodId = order[0].productId;
    return collectionProducts.findOne({"_id": prodId})
      .then(currentProduct => {
        if (currentProduct) {
          var obj = { /* stuff */ }
        }
        else { obj = ""; }
      return Promise.resolve(obj);
    })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it didn't help. Still only one version of the orders with multiple items comes through.

Comment: I just noticed that the array passed on to the decorateProducts had extra [ ] around the orders with multiple products, which seems to cause the problem. Thanks anyways and sorry for the trouble.